# How to temporarily disable a Run Script phase in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcodebuild

I have a Run Script phase configured for my project's target. It is run on every build. Is it possible to temporarily disable this script without removing it from the target?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I don't know of any sort of "disabled" state. However, it's a bash script, so you could just add `exit 0` at the top while you want it disabled.

Answer (score 13):

Or if it's a single line script you could just add a `#` at the beginning to comment the statement out.